# VS Code Stop Support for Yosemite Mac OS 10.10 as Electron fails

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, osx-yosemite

I was using VS Code on Mac OS 10.10.5 Yosemite, without problems but even though at VS Code's site there's a claim that it works on version 10.10+, it seems there was a change because after I installed and linked it to Anaconda, first it failed to load and now is also giving an error when I opened Electron, inside the package it returned this

```
Process:               Electron [2136]
Path:                  /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
Identifier:            Electron
Version:               ???
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [1969]
Responsible:           Terminal [388]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-05-13 00:53:58.380 -0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F2511)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        4A727D22-D456-25CE-01E7-5229FC050D38

Sleep/Wake UUID:       00E47028-065E-46DE-A826-6A0637E80EF6

Time Awake Since Boot: 44000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: ___NSArray0__
  Referenced from: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/ReactiveObjC.framework/ReactiveObjC (which was built for Mac OS X 10.11)
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
 in /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/ReactiveObjC.framework/ReactiveObjC
```

and also the same information is in Terminal if you run Electron

```
Referenced from: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/ReactiveObjC.framework/ReactiveObjC (which was built for Mac OS X 10.11)
```

so it seems they quietly discontinued support for Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite ...
When I tried to open the app using the finder I got an alert saying 'this is an application for Mac OS 10.11 an onwards ...', among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the Jan2021 older version of VS code and was able to successfully download and launch it. https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_53

Comment: I don't know what you did @user16077776, but I tried your link and same thing on 10.10.5 after unzipping it renders the familiar blocked icon, and when you try to open it, displays the same error message ...

Comment: My mistake I was downloading the wrong link, I had to download the Mac 64, version, that's on a link at the top and disregard the large Blue Download button, that's at the top Right, it saves the Universal version that has the same problem described above.
The one you need to download is VSCode-darwin.zip

Comment: Also add "update.mode": "none" to settings.json, or otherwise VSCode will immediately re-break itself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162685/how-do-i-disable-vs-code-of-updating-itself

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several version by now and can safely say that:

March 2021 (version 1.55) is last supported version for OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55