# Cannot use vscode on macOS 10.14.6

Tags: visual-studio-code, download, version, macos-mojave, incompatibility

Vscode cannot be used in conjunction with macOS Mojave 10.14.6 as it automatically updates to v1.86.1. I tried to obtain the old version of vscode, but encountered the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6ZmY.png)

How should I solve the issue of version incompatibility? Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it. just use a download link from the top of the page at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85#_macos-1013-and-1014-support-has-ended, and disable VS Code updates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50162685/11107541. are you doing that already?

Comment: I can corroborate that this month, VS Code has inexplicably stopped working on my 10.14.6 Mac despite having disabled updates.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Mojave 10.14.6 the updated version of Visual Studio Code may not work. Try deleting the current Visual Studio Code version off of your macOS, and then download and install the Visual Studio Code version 1.85.2 found here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_85